# Только начал учить python

Tags: python

Выдает ошибку:

> ```
> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
> ```

КОД:

```
a = float( input("введи первое число:") )
what = input("что будем делать? (+,-,*,/)")
b = float( input("введи второе число:") )


if what == "+":
        c = a + b
        print("получится" + str(c))

    if what == "-":
        c = a - b
        print("получится" + str(c))
    
    if what == "*":
        c = a * b
        print(str(c))
        
    if what == "/":
        c = a / b
        print(str(c))

elif:
    print("Можно вводить только числа или арифметические выражения, приведенные выше, 
для получения ответа")

input()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: На отступы ругается. Отступы в питоне являются элементами синтаксиса. Конкретно — сразу после первого if две строчки на отступ дальше, чем надо.

Comment: Я хотел всё соединить и поэтому сделал 4 отступа плюс 4 отступа для следующего условия, которое хотел привязать

Answer (score 2):

Вы наверно хотели сделать это:

```
a = float(input("введи первое число: "))
what = input("что будем делать (+, - , *, /)? ")
b = float(input("введи второе число: "))

if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print("получится " + str(c))

elif what == "-":
    c = a - b
    print("получится " + str(c))
    
elif what == "*":
    c = a * b
    print(str(c))
        
elif what == "/":
    c = a / b
    print(str(c))

else:
    print("Можно вводить только числа или арифметические выражения, приведенные выше, для получения ответа")

input()
```

Я исправил отступы и кроме того вместо второго, третьего и четвертого `if` применил `elif`, чтобы программа работала правильно и чтобы `еlse` было связано со всеми остальными возможностями.

Относительно отступов, они должны **быть** идентичны, не только **выглядеть** идентичными. Значит, когда вы для одного отступа применили пробелы и для второго клавиш <kbd>Tab</kbd>, **они не будут идентичными**, хотя так могут выглядеть.